# Magento - Dataflow error - Path "path/filename.csv" is not available and cannot be used

Tags: magento

I'm receiving an error in Magento when trying to use the Dataflow export feature.

`Path "path/filename.csv" is not available and cannot be used.`

This feature used to work perfectly fine before, so I don't know what could be going wrong. I've checked permissions on the folder and files and they are fine (777). In addition, I've tried deleting the existing file or trying different path names and still no dice.

After some more testing, it seems that this is only occurring with a path that I have personally created. When using a path created by Magento such as var/export, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik this has to do with some dataflow changes around 1.4 or 1.5, where Varien started to restrict dataflow profiles for type `Local Server` to specific directory and file masks:

```
array(
    'export_xml' => 'var/export/*/*.xml',
    'export_csv' => 'var/export/*/*.csv',
    'import_xml' => 'var/import/*/*.xml',
    'import_csv' => 'var/import/*/*.csv'
);
```

With Magento default settings this means, that your export files *must* reside inside the `var/export` or one of its subfolder like `var/export/mydir/my.csv'.

Magento 1.5.1 in fact shows an appropriate hint in the Profile Wizard:

> (For Type "Local Server" need to use
>   relative path to Magento install
>   var/export or var/import, e.g.
>   var/export, var/import,
>   var/export/some/dir,
>   var/import/some/dir)

I only skimmed thru the source code, but I guess to use your own paths outside `var/export` you need to override `Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_AvailablePath::isValid()` and/or override `Mage_ImportExport_Helper_Data::getLocalValidPaths()`.

More easier will be to use symlinks (thanks @ColinM for mentioning that), but this will of course only work on systems, where the usage of symlinks is allowed/activated.

Comment: Interesting that you mention that, I was able to use that directory with 1.5.0.1, but after updating to 1.5.1.0 it no longer works. It's possible that the upgrade is the cause. I'll look further into this.

Answer (score 4):

Not need override `Mage_ImportExport_Helper_Data::getLocalValidPaths()`

Just need add to config.xml at self module

```
<config>
<default>
    <general>
        <file>
            <importexport_local_valid_paths>
                <available>
                    <my_new_path_to_csv>var/import/*/*.csv</my_new_path_to_csv>
                </available>
            </importexport_local_valid_paths>
        </file>
    </general>
</default>
</config>
```

This issue must be resolve this way.

Comment: solution worked in 1.9.3.2.I want to make path like `media/customerexport/*/*.csv` to download csv.

Comment: That's the right solution and works great! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem after updating from Magento 1.4 to 1.7.
The filenames are more restrictive. To ensure that you use the right filename, just delete the content of the filename field in your export profile.
Magento will then automatically insert a valid filename when you save the profile.

Comment: This worked for me. When using var/export and export.xls, I got an error. When emptying both fields, they were filled in by magento and it all worked. I had to rename the xml file to xlsx and then could open it in Libreoffice (or Excel).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a hosted server with a large provider, sometimes `chmod 777` is not allowed for security reasons. Try `755` on the folder instead and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I've got my own dedicated server with full root access, so I imagine that it should be alright. Either way, I tested out 755 and it didn't work.

Comment: In that case, you might need to dump the variables when you run the command and see where it is trying to drop the files. That would be my only suggestion, that it might not have the correct full path.

Answer (score 0):

I had left the file extension off. I added .csv at the end and all was good.